# Al realizar la consulta el la base de datos de Firebase y mostralo en un RecyclerView solo me trae 1 dato de cada uno de los elementos de todos

Tags: android-studio, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firestore

Es una implementación de una actividad de Android que muestra una lista de eventos. En el método onCreate, se infla la vista correspondiente a la actividad y se configura el adaptador de RecyclerView para mostrar la lista de eventos. El adaptador utilizado es ScrolAdapter, que extiende la clase FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. Se crea una instancia de FirestoreRecyclerOptions que se utiliza para configurar el adaptador. En el método onStart, se llama al método startListening del adaptador para comenzar a escuchar los cambios en la base de datos de Firestore. En el método onStop, se llama al método stopListening del adaptador para detener la escucha de cambios en la base de datos.

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public ScrolAdapter tarjetaAdapter;
    FirebaseFirestore mfirestore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.ReciclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mfirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        Query query = mfirestore.collection("Eventos")
                .orderBy("Registro")
                .limit(50);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions <Evento> firestoreRecyclerOptions =
                new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Evento>().setQuery(query, Evento.class).build();
        tarjetaAdapter = new ScrolAdapter(firestoreRecyclerOptions);
        tarjetaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(tarjetaAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        tarjetaAdapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        tarjetaAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
}
```

Es una implementación de un adaptador de RecyclerView que se utiliza para mostrar una lista de eventos. La clase ScrolAdapter extiende la clase FirestoreRecyclerAdapter y tiene dos métodos principales: onBindViewHolder y onCreateViewHolder. El método onBindViewHolder se llama cada vez que se necesita actualizar un elemento en la lista y se encarga de actualizar los datos de la vista correspondiente. El método onCreateViewHolder se llama cuando se necesita crear una nueva vista para un elemento de la lista. En este caso, se infla una vista a partir del archivo de diseño item_evento.xml y se devuelve un nuevo objeto ViewHolder que contiene las vistas correspondientes.

```
public class ScrolAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Evento,ScrolAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    /**
     * Create a new RecyclerView adapter that listens to a Firestore Query.  See {@link
     * FirestoreRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public ScrolAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Evento> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Evento evento) {
        holder.state.setText(evento.getEstado());
        holder.title.setText(evento.getTitulo());
        holder.impacto.setText(evento.getImpacto());
        holder.fechaini.setText(evento.getFecha_ini());
        holder.fechafin.setText(evento.getFecha_fin());
        holder.creador.setText(evento.getUsuario());
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_evento,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView title,state,impacto,fechaini,fechafin,creador;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            state = itemView.findViewById(R.id.state);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            impacto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.impacto_view);
            fechaini = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fecha_finview);
            fechafin = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fecha_finview);
            creador = itemView.findViewById(R.id.creador);
        }
    }

}
```

clase evento
En esta clase ponemos el constructor y creamos los Getters y Setters de los variables pertenecientes a la clase eventos

```
public class Evento {
   private String Titulo,estado,impacto,fecha_ini,fecha_fin,usuario,cargo,correo,descripcion,registro;

    public Evento(String ntitulo, String nestado, String nimpacto, String nfecha_ini, String nfecha_fin, String nusuario,String ncargo,String ncorreo,String ndescripcion,String nregistro) {
        estado = nestado;
        Titulo = ntitulo;
        impacto = nimpacto;
        fecha_ini = nfecha_ini;
        fecha_fin = nfecha_fin;
        usuario = nusuario;
        cargo = ncargo;
        descripcion = ndescripcion;
        correo = ncorreo;
        registro = nregistro;
    }
    public Evento() {}
    public String getTitulo() {return Titulo;}
............................................}
```

Comment: Saludos, el código debe ir en formato de texto por favor, recuerda que siempre puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/607404/edit) tu pregunta. ;)

Comment: Agrega todo el código de tu adapter, y agrega el código como texto, ya que no se ve bien como imagen. No olvides revisar [ask].

Comment: Ya lo modifique espero su pronta colaboración

Answer (score 0):

Cada campo en el modelo debe coincidir con el nombre de un campo en los documentos de Firebase. osea que si en Firebase se llama Title en Evento debe llamarse Title